# PHP OO Dynamic Class Methods Implementations Based on Database Connection

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4, interface

I'm building a system that extracts data from different databases (client's databases), filter the data and store locally. The data stored will be the same for everyone (clients, stores, transactions) but the data coming from different databases won't be the same. I need to filter this data based on their database, example:

I have the following model (I'm using **LaravelPHP**): `Client` - With this model I can call `Client::filterData($data)` and that will work for a specific client. I wanna use the same model and method to filter my data but using a different interface based on the client's database.

It's like e-commerce does with their Shipment classes/methods. They have a parent class that extends from different types of shipments.

If it's not clear enough, I can make my explaining better. I hope you guys can help me figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of dependency injection, where Laravel suffers (due to its bunch of static calls and tight-coupling).

Comment: How do I solve my problem?

Comment: I found similar issue here: http://laravel.io/forum/05-27-2014-use-eloquent-relationships-with-another-database?page=1

Comment: You will have to code it yourself (just create one `abstract` model and extend it for different connections), or you can switch to Zend or Symfony where you can do this without a pain

Comment: Or even you can try `DB::reconnect('another_database');` inside a model when init event fires

Comment: can you formulate an answer with an example for me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Client - With this model I can call Client::filterData($data) and that
>   will work for a specific client. I wanna use the same model and method
>   to filter my data but using a different interface based on the
>   client's database.

What you're really looking for is how to replace database connection during the runtime. Unfortunately Laravel doesn't support Dependency Injection well, therefore you will have to workaround this just to make it work:

```
abstract class AbstractClient extends Eloquent
{
   // move everything from Client class into this one
}
```

Then simply extend it and define a connection you want to use inside `init()` method

```
class Client extends AbstractClient 
{
       public funciton init()
       {
           DB::reconnect('client_database');
       }
}
```

For another client:

```
class AnotherClient extends AbstractClient 
{
       public funciton init()
       {
           DB::reconnect('another_client_database');
       }
}
```

This way you can set-up the same model for different connections. Of course it needs to be improved, I left it for you.

Comment: 2 questions: How do I pass the database name to the init function? How do I work around the different fields? Example: In one DB I can have as (name, email, etc), in another DB the client can have (first_name, last_name, email) and I need to filter this differently.

Comment: As for first question, that's a very basic thing to do described here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#accessing-connections (The point: You just define connection details in array, and then read it by calling `reconnect()` method.

Comment: As for second question, that will be a bit harder especially when amount of fields in one table might not be equal to amount of fields in another. However, this question was about how to connect to different databases using the same model. Your second question is a separated topic

Comment: The data will be different but the final result must be the same, my local database will store the same kind of information, but the data comes from different databases that are using different ecommerces and it needs to be filtered differently. That's my main question.